# Usage of ant design on server side

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, antd, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to render my project on server side and facing some issues with ant design.

I am using vite + react + typescript for my SSR app.

The error message i get is

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SSR\ssr\node_modules\antd\es\input\TextArea.js:1
import _toConsumableArray from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray";
^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
        at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
        at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
        at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
        at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
        at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
    C:\Users\user\Desktop\SSR\ssr\node_modules\antd\es\input\TextArea.js:1
    import _toConsumableArray from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray";
    ^^^^^^
```

I have already changed type to module in my package.json file

```
"type": "module",
```

Following is my vite.config.ts file

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
// import macrosPlugin from 'vite-plugin-babel-macros'
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";
// import path from 'path'
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// How to migrate from CRA to vite: https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/migrating-from-create-react-app-cra-to-vite

import dns from "dns";

dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env": {},
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "stream",
        replacement: `stream-browserify`,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  ssr: {
    noExternal: ["styled-components", "@emotion/*", /(node_modules)/],
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8000,
  },
});
```

And my tsconfig.json file is as follows

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "vite/client"],
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: i'm facing the same issue, Has any workaround been found so far?

Comment: I used the TextArea from the antd input component. It solved the issue. -->  

import { Input } from 'antd'

<Input.TextArea ..............